# Text overflow: ellipsis doesn't apply correctly on a p: class

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on  project that is a mobile first one. I have a list of elements but I have a problem with one of them.
To explain what I want, in my project I always want "h3" to be entirely visible, so the customer can read it. On the other side, I want my "meal__description" to be cropped if it's too long so the price doesn't move away from the box. I've tried to change the width of it but it's doing some weird stuff with my hover effect..
Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide to me!

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
}

.meal .meal__block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0000002e;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in both, top 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.meal__description {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.meal__price {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.meal .meal__text h3,
.meal__description {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.meal__description {
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
}

.meal .meal__circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #99E2D0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0rem;
  width: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.9rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.9rem;
  left: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.38rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.meal div:hover .meal__circle {
  left: 80%;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 20%;
}

.meal div:hover .meal__text {
  width: 65%;
}

.meal div:hover .meal__price {
  animation: move-animation 0.2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move-animation {
  from {
    padding-right: 1%;
  }
  to {
    padding-right: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="meal">
  <section>
    <div class="meal__block">
      <div class="meal__text">
        <h3>Filet de boeuf aux herbes</h3>
        <p class="meal__description">Accompagné de sa ribambelle de légumes</p>
      </div>
      <p class="meal__price">40€</p>
      <div class="meal__circle">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meal__block">
      <div class="meal__text">
        <h3>Parmentier de queue de boeuf</h3>
        <p class="meal__description">À la truffe noire sur sa purée de panais</p>
      </div>
      <p class="meal__price">35€</p>
      <div class="meal__circle">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meal__block">
      <div class="meal__text">
        <h3>Filet de turbot</h3>
        <p class="meal__description">Aux agrumes</p>
      </div>
      <p class="meal__price">44€</p>
      <div class="meal__circle">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: For the ellipsis you need to give `width` to the container, it can't be 100%. Try to fix it for example to 100px or 50% and you'll see the ellipsis works.

Comment: Yeah I understand this, however I want my ellipsis to work only on the "meal__description" and not the h3, but I still need the ellipsis for both of those elements when the hover effect is on.

Comment: You have ellipsis declared this way `.meal .meal__text h3, .meal__description` so it works both for h3 and for 'meal__description'. Just move the ellipsis styles form this class to this one `.meal__description`

Comment: Yeah but like i said, I would like the ellipsis to work on the h3 when the hover effect is on.

Comment: Try to add more text both to h3 and to .meal__description. Both texts reach the end of the container. What would you like to happen?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` will fix your issue.

```css
.meal__text {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```